# An integral involving the Cauchy integral formula

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

I want to calculate the following integral for my homework assignment:
$$ \int_{\lvert z \rvert = 2}\frac{2z^2 - 1}{5z^3 + 1} \, \mathrm d z.$$
I think I need to use Cauchy's integral formula but I do not see how to. I struggle to do a partial fractions decomposition. I know that all three zeros of the denominator are in the ball with radius $2$. Maybe that might help?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)?

Comment: No, we did not treat it. So I cannot use it. There must be an easier way!

Comment: Once you compute the partial fraction decomposition you can split the integral in three integrals that each has the form of Cauchy's integral formula. The zeros of the denominator are simple. So, you could use the [cover-up method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method). A little enhancement that you can do is to note that evaluating $(z-r)\frac{2z^2-1}{5z^3+1}$  at $z=r$, where $r$ is one of the roots, is the same as evaluating $\frac{2z^2-1}{15z^2}$ at $z=r$. The denominator $15z^2$ is the derivative of $5z^3+1$

Comment: Another approach, since you observed that all singular points are inside your contour, is to make a change of variable $z=1/w$ to send all singular points out. You will get a single singular point at $w=0$. Then you don't even need to do partial fraction decomposition, but only apply Cauchy's integral formula once.

Comment: @plop Could you write a solution? I am very confused at the moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the *explicit* partial fraction decomposition of the integrand. It suffices to see that
$$
\int_{|z|=r}\frac{2z^2 - 1}{5z^3 + 1} \, dz
$$
does not depend on $r$ once the circle $|z|=r$ encloses all roots of the denominator. Therefore
$$
\int_{|z|=2}\frac{2z^2 - 1}{5z^3 + 1} \, dz = \lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{|z|=r}\frac{2z^2 - 1}{5z^3 + 1} \, dz = 2 \pi i \cdot \frac 25
$$
because
$$
\frac{2z^2 - 1}{5z^3 + 1}  = \frac{2}{5z} + O\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)
$$
for $z \to \infty$.